# What event(s) can be fired on ui.router transition to a sticky state?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app which is using ui.router and the plugin ui.router-extras, specifically the sticky-state module.  This allows me to cache the rendered DOM from a given parent state downwards.

The problem is that when I transition to a state that I've set as 'sticky' (i.e. cached), none of the events associated with that state fire.  OnEnter and Resolve have both run already and are cached, it seems.

```
states.push({ name: 'root.planner',             url: 'planner',
              abstract: true,
              views: {
                'planner-tab':  {
                  controller: 'planner',   
                  templateUrl: 'views/planner/_planner.html'
                }
              },
              sticky:true,
              deepStateRedirect: true
            });
states.push({ name: 'root.planner.home',   url: '',
              controller: 'planner.home',
              templateUrl: 'views/planner/_planner.home.html',
              resolve: {
                'promiseDays': function(PlannerService){
                  return PlannerService.getDays();
                }
              },
              onEnter: function(StatusService){
                //set editable
                StatusService.toggleEditIcon(true);
              },
              onExit: function(StatusService){
                //set editable
                StatusService.toggleEditIcon(false);
              }
            });
```

What I need is a way to allow OnEnter to run or some similar event that can be tailored to each state.  Ideally, this would be inside the state config above (so I can avoid doing a state-name check on every stateChangeSuccess, for instance), but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

From the [issue](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/122) raised on GitHub, Christ T (developer of ui-router-extras) helpfully suggested this:

"While it's not documented, Sticky states will invoke onInactivate and onReactivate callbacks. See the source code at the following lines:"

[onInactivate](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onInactivate)

[onReactivate](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onReactivate)

Which works perfectly for me.

Comment: linky to search in the repo instead of hardcoded github file: https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onReactivate

Comment: Thanks, @Michael.  Good spot.